# Creating a test script for editing the user details using the jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am new to Jmeter, I have one scenario where I need to do a load test i.e editing a user's details.

-> Need to login with credentials

->Need to update the values

Above steps need to be performed for 500 users. My doubt is when I am editing the user details I don't want to edit all the details of the user. I just want to change the status of the user to inactive. For this I have recorded the script, to do this I need to pass the id of the user and all values which I am not changing. Is the right way taking all these values in a excel sheet and passing those values to request? Is there any way to achieve it?

Any help/ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the information from .csv file.

If the file has to be Excel and you cannot convert it to CSV you can still get information from it but it will be a little bit tricky. See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) to learn how to do it.